# How to uninstall vue-cli 2.x.x

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

Even after using the npm uninstall command, I still can use the vue command.

```
christianjavan@rog:~$ sudo npm uninstall  vue-cli
npm WARN christianjavan@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN christianjavan@1.0.0 No repository field.

up to date in 0.781s
found 0 vulnerabilities

christianjavan@rog:~$ vue -V
2.9.2
christianjavan@rog:~$ sudo npm uninstall -g vue-cli
up to date in 0.039s
christianjavan@rog:~$ sudo npm uninstall vue-cli
npm WARN christianjavan@1.0.0 No description
npm WARN christianjavan@1.0.0 No repository field.

up to date in 0.721s
found 0 vulnerabilities

christianjavan@rog:~$ vue -V
2.9.2
christianjavan@rog:~$ npm update
christianjavan@rog:~$ sudo npm update
christianjavan@rog:~$ vue -V
2.9.2
```

I already tried to completely remove nodejs and reinstall, but it doesn't seem to work either.

Any ideas on how to remove the vue-cli 2.x.x?

Comment: Where is it installed? (run `which vue`)

Comment: you should try `npm list -g --depth 0` to see the global package list, if the vue-cli install by yarn, should run `yarn global list` and unintall by `yarn remove global vue-cli`

Comment: @tony19 it is installed on /usr/bin/vue.

Comment: @masongzhi when I run the npm list command, it says that vue cli 3.0.0 is installed, but when I run the vue -V command, it says that I have the 2.9.2 installed.

https://i.imgur.com/0en5DHv.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[SOLUTION]**

Here is how I solved it.

using `which vue` I saw where vue was installed.

```
christianjavan@rog:$ which vue
/usr/bin/vue
```

Then I deleted all vue files inside the installation folder

```
christianjavan@rog:/usr/bin$ sudo rm -rf vue
christianjavan@rog:/usr/bin$ sudo rm -rf vue-init
christianjavan@rog:/usr/bin$ sudo rm -rf vue-list
```

Then I did exactly what it says in [this link](https://docs.npmjs.com/getting-started/fixing-npm-permissions#option-2-change-npms-default-directory-to-another-directory).

```
christianjavan@rog:/$ mkdir ~/.npm-global
mkdir: cannot create directory ‘/home/christianjavan/.npm-global’: File exists
christianjavan@rog:/$ npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'
christianjavan@rog:/$ export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
christianjavan@rog:/$ source ~/.profile
```

Then I tried to install the new vue cli

```
christianjavan@rog:/$ npm install -g @vue/cli
```

Then I did vue --version and finally got the 3.0.3 version installed

```
christianjavan@rog:/$ vue --version
3.0.3
```

NOTE: After trying to run vue -V again later, it did't found the vue command, so I exported the new vue directory to the PATH. When you run `npm install -g @vue/cli` the command gives you the new vue directory.

```
christianjavan@rog:~$ npm install -g @vue/cli
/home/christianjavan/.npm-global/bin/vue -> /home/christianjavan/.npm-global/lib/node_modules/@vue/cli/bin/vue.js
```

You add that directory to your PATH.

```
christianjavan@rog:~$ export PATH=$PATH:/home/christianjavan/.npm-global/bin
```

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're missing a [flag to determine context](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/uninstall); maybe try `sudo npm uninstall -g vue-cli` (or `-S` or `-D` as needed)

Comment: Didn't seem to work, I used all the flags, but the CLI is still there.

https://i.imgur.com/65cUjcR.png

Answer (score 0):

make use of this command: npm install -g @vue/cli --force